# AngularJs - best way to limit access to 'logged in' users

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm struggling with setting up a login system for an app i'm creating.

I'm able to set cookies for when the user is logged in or out. I don't think that testing every view if the user is logged in is a very elegant solution, and i'm afraid a page here and there may fall through the cracks (it's a rather large app).

I'm thinking the best way would be to intercept route changes somehow and check if the user is logged in, otherwise send them to a login/create user page. I've found a few methods, but nothing seems to be officially documented. Has anyone used this type of method in a real world case, and was it effective?

My route file looks like this:

```
'use strict';

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // LOGIN
        .when('/User/LoginUser', {templateUrl: 'views/user/login.html',controller: 'loginCtrl'})

    ....... more routes here.......

        // DEFAULT
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

Any help or suggestions, or points to documented real world examples of how I would do something like this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My first thought jumped to "server side" and "session" here.

Comment: I use routing in my app as well and I utilize ajax calls for session data. I use this as a way to determine the users role as well as user logged in session status.

Comment: Server side is not an option.

@Asok I'm hoping for a higher level solution so that I won't have to repeatedly ask the server if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can intercept route changes as you suggested and act accordingly, using the following example as a basis:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        var userAuthenticated = ...; /* Check if the user is logged in */

        if (!userAuthenticated && !next.isLogin) {
            /* You can save the user's location to take him back to the same page after he has logged-in */
            $rootScope.savedLocation = $location.url();

            $location.path('/User/LoginUser');
        }
    });
```

Also, add `isLogin: true` to the route definition of your login page, like this:

```
$routeProvider
    // LOGIN
    .when('/User/LoginUser', {templateUrl: 'views/user/login.html',controller: 'loginCtrl', isLogin: true})
```

Good luck with your project!

Comment: what does adding "isLogin: true" do? it's not documented in the latest angularJS documentation

Comment: `isLogin` is not a part of the `angular-router` API, it is simply a variable that we check inside our `$routeChangeStart` listener implementation (see the `if` statement)

Comment: This is checking for isLogin of next route. What is a user refreshes the same page, it is not redirecting then ?

Answer (score -17):

My opinion:

```
<?php if (!$_SESSION['user_id'] { forward(/user/access); }) ?>
```

and here comes your angular app...

Comment: It's 2014. We can do better than this. :-)

Comment: I'm sure it's and there should be a way, but in certain applications (online banking for example) you can't just display the visual interface of an online banking account, even when there's no values or no information.

Comment: I would delete this answer to avoid the shame haha

Comment: 2 years ago, and I do still think the same way, after having done a few angular applications without any problem. And I usually change my mind, in this case, I didn't, I still believe that in some cases, showing, even the plain, useless <html> code of your interface, is a risk. And you clearly don't work in security.