# AngularJs logged in user permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, user-interface, ruby-on-rails-4

#### Background

I am building an app which displays different content on a page depending on whether a user is logged in or not. (using ng-if) I do not wish to redirect users to separate routes depending on logged in status. 
[AngularJs - best way to limit access to 'logged in' users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918579/angularjs-best-way-to-limit-access-to-logged-in-users)

I do have server validations in check to make sure only true logged in users can modify, but I would like to prevent non users from viewing certain content. I am unsure what the best approach is to do this. Right now I am certain that this is bad.

- AngularJS
- Rails 4

#### In my Static Page html.erb file

```
<script>
    window.loggedin = <%= signed_in? %>; 
</script>
```

#### In my Rails Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    helper_method :signed_in?

    private

    def current_user
        return nil if !session[:session_token]
        @user ||= User.find_by_session_token(session[:session_token])
    end

    def signed_in?
        !!current_user
    end
end
```

#### In my Angular Controller

```
$scope.loggedIn = function(){
    return window.loggedin;
};
```

#### Question

What is the proper("secure") way of doing this?

Comment: Is your login on the front-end done via the Angular app? Or is it purely rails?

Comment: my login is done purely in rails currently...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User access control (Authentication) is always a **server-side affair**. In other words, your server should always be performing authentication checks on every request - not the client. There's nothing you can do on the client side to prevent users from communicating directly with your server.

What it sounds like you're trying to do with Angular is **visibility control** based on a users authentication state which is set by the server. It looks like you have the right idea with `$scope.loggedIn`. You definitely need a way to know whether or not the user has been authenticated.

You shouldn't, however, do `window.loggedIn` because anyone can change the state of the window object. It's not necessarily less secure, but it's definitely not a good solution. As a general rule of thumb, avoid global variables.

Here's one architecture that I recommend:

- An authentication **service** that communicates with your authentication server
- A session **factory** that represents a users session. You might want this to hold the users ID or whatever. If this is missing an ID, then the user is not authenticated
- A function in a top-level scope object (maybe $rootScope? or just a top level controller scope?) to declare in templates

Here's how it will look:

**Top level Controller**

```
.controller("ApplicationController", function($scope, AuthService) {
  $scope.isAuthenticated = function() {
    return AuthService.isAuthenticated();
  };
});
```

**Authentication Service**

```
.service("AuthService", function($http, UserSession) {
   this.login = function() { ... };
   this.logout = function() { ... };
   this.isAuthenticated = function() {
     return UserSession.exists();
   };
});
```

**Session Factory**

```
.factory("UserSession", function() {
  var currUserId = null;
  return {
    createSession: function(userId) {
      currUserId = userId;
    },
    destroySession: function() {
      currUserId = null;
    },
    exists: function() {
      return currUserId !== null;
    }
  }; 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="isAuthenticated()"> ... </div>
```

This seems more complex but I like it because its modular design makes it very easy to extend and reuse. Code not tested but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks this is great! I was building my own Auth service, but this plan will work.