# Angularjs / Coldfusion - Identification module - retrieve user role before implementing routes controller and views

Tags: angularjs, service, coldfusion, routes, angular-promise

I develop an application with Angularjs. In order to access to the application, the user has to be identified thanks to an external system (not developed by myself).
When the user is correctly identified, this external system redirected to my application.

I have implemented a general remote service for retrieving data (thanks to Coldfusion and an Oracle database) about a user (thanks to the login). This service is equally used in other applications. It returns general user information: firstname, lastname,..., and the user role for the specific application.

I would like to authorize the access to the sections of my application when the user has the corresponding role.

Thus I have called once the function of this service before to implement the routes in order to avoid many calls to the functions in the controllers. It works and I retrieve the user role.

```
var app=angular.module('ContactsApp', ['ngRoute', 'RemoteService']);

// CALL the method from THE REMOTE SERVICE - used $http.get and retrieve JSON data
app.factory('RemoteServiceFunction', ['RemoteServiceFactory', function (RemoteServiceFactory) {
return RemoteServiceFactory.Auth_getUserFromLogin(userid)
}]);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){

// FUNCTION USING THE REMOTE SERVICE IN ORDER TO INJECT DATA IN THE ROUTES
var wait = ['RemoteServiceFunction', function(RemoteServiceFunction) {
    return RemoteServiceFunction;
}];



$routeProvider.when('/all-contacts',
{
  templateUrl: 'template/allContacts.html',
  controller: 'ctrlContacts', 
    resolve: {
        personInfo: wait
    }           
})
.when('/view-contacts/:contactId',
{
  templateUrl: 'template/viewContact.html',
  controller: 'ctrlViewContacts',
    resolve: {
        personInfo: wait
    }         
})
.when('/search-contacts',
{
  templateUrl: 'template/fastSearch.html',
  controller: 'ctrlContactSearch',
    resolve: {
        personInfo: wait
    }         
})  
.when('/add-contacts',
{
  templateUrl: 'template/manageContact.html',
  controller: 'ctrlAddContacts',
    resolve: {
        personInfo: wait
    }         
}) 
.otherwise({redirectTo:'/all-contacts'});  
});    

//THE CONTROLERS WITH DEPENDANCIES INJECTED
app.controller('ctrlContacts', function ($scope, ContactService, personInfo){
// alert(personInfoRole.data["VALUES"][0]["ROLES"]); OK the role is retrieved
}
```

Now I would like to enable or not the access to the various sections ( for example the role "admin" is mandatory for example in order to add a contact: ctrlAddContacts) . I do not know if I have to add a condition or a function in the resolve part to give the access.

Could you please tell me how to do that? Or tell me if another solution is better for using roles with Angularjs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to "intercept" the route change, that is: listening to the `$routeChangeStart` event on your rootScope. There you can check against whatever model variable you store the user priviledge in, and stop the routeChange from happening or redirect to an authentication screen.

Keep in mind though that such client-side authentication in an angular *(or any javascript)* application is just a user interface thing, since the user's browser will have full access to all the resources, and can even rewrite the validating parts of the javascript code, bypassing any route restrictions you set up. Sensitive information shouldn't travel to the client in the first place without proper authentication.

edit: see a full code solution here:[best way to limit access to 'logged in' users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18922530/4083826)